# doubt on transformer working and dc current

Tags: electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

In my textbook, it indicates:
**Transformers don't work on DC**
To which I agree.

But next, it also indicated that:
**It is not necessary that DC neither changes in magnitude nor in direction.**

The 2nd statement seems confusing to me.  Why would DC do that? I thought DC didn't vary? Isn't that the character of AC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC can have magnitude which varies with time. But polarity i.e. direction of DC can not change with time. Best example for this is DC obtained by rectifying AC. This will have varying magnitude but constant direction. So second statement is partially correct and partially wrong.